# What is the best way to initialize listjs with divs

Tags: javascript, listjs

I am attempting to make a searchable database with list.js but the search function is not working. I am not sure if I initialized it correctly or what I am doing wrong. I am sure it is something obvious but I would love another set of eyes.

Here is my HTML

```
<body>  

<div class="hof-list">

<input class="search" placeholder="Search for a member..."/><br>

    <div class="list">

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">Lucille Ball</div>
            <div class="year">2018</div>
        </div>

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">Jeremy Jacobs</div>
            <div class="year">2018</div>
        </div>

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">Russell Salvatore</div>
            <div class="year">2018</div>
        </div>

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">John Albright</div>
            <div class="year">2017</div>
        </div>

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">Lousie Bethune</div>
            <div class="year">2017</div>
        </div>

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">Glenn Curtis</div>
            <div class="year">2017</div>
        </div>

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">John Oishei</div>
            <div class="year">2018</div>
        </div>          

        <div class="objects">
            <div class="name">Mary Burnett Talbert</div>
            <div class="year">2017</div>            
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my script

```
var options = {
  valueNames: ['name', 'year']
};

var hoflist = new List('hof-list', options);
```

Comment: Try to set `hof-list` as an id, according to documentation: `new List(id/element, options, values);`

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was something simple like that! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://listjs.com/api/) it expects the following parameters: `new List(id/element, options, values);` where `id/element` is

> id or element *required Id the element in which the list area should be initialized. OR the actual element itself.

So you should pass there an actual id (so you need to change it in your html), or, you can pass there an element with

```
new List(document.querySelector('.hof-list'), options)
```